# How to include AEM parsys in page component

Tags: aem, sightly

I have the following line, in the page component file /apps/my-app/components/pages/homepage/body.html

`<div data-sly-resource="${ @path='right-parsys',resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>`

And we are getting log messaages

> [.... GET /content/our-system/home/en.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.LiveRelationshipManager
>   Impl StarResource given at /content/our-system/home/en/jcr:content/right-parsys/*: no parent: no LiveCopy

I have the following questions: Is the paragraph system properly added to the sightly page component? It seems to work ok. This is a second paragraph drop zone  in the right positioned column. I've also seen it this way `data-sly-resource="${granite.resource.path @ resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}` what's the difference?

What is meant by 'Star Resource' in the context of the logged warning? Given the [sightly documentation](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html#resource) I still don't quite get the usage of the @ symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log messages you're seeing are not related to Sightly itself, but rather the LiveCopy status of the page that's being rendered. If the parsys render output is correct it means it is properly included by the body page component.

The "@" symbol is being used by Sightly to delimit expression options; the same mechanism is being used to send parameters when invoking sightly templates or including other resources via data-sly-resource.

In other words, the parameters for the data-sly-resource inclusion need to be provided after the "@" symbol.
The differences between the two examples you provided are minor: in the first statement the 'right-parsys' child resource of the current resource will be included using the 'wcm/foundation/components/parsys' resource type; the second statement will include the current resource using the 'wcm/foundation/components/parsys' resource type.